# Killing a process when some other process is finished

Tags: shell-script, pipe, kill, job-control

Given `a | b`, i'd like to kill `b` when `a` is finished. `b` is an interactive process, which doesn't terminates when `a` is finished ([`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) in my case), and the whole `a | b` is executed in a `$()` subshell.

So far what i come up with was

```
echo $({ sleep 5 & a=$!; { wait $a; kill $b; } } | { fzf & b=$!; })
```

`sleep` represents `a`, and `fzf` represents `b`, the result in the example is used by `echo`, but in my case, it'd be an argument for `ssh`. It seems, that `$b` is not the PID of `fzf`, it's empty. As far as i understand, this shouldn't be the case, since i've used `{}`, and not `()`, so it's not executed in a subshell.

Comment: Maybe start `a|b` in the background and use `pgrep` to poll for a, then `pkill` to kill b as soon as a is gone.

Comment: @Jaleks I can't start `a|b` in the background, as `b` requires user interaction.

Comment: kk, sorry, thought It would be some GUI process, did not look up fzf. Maybe then start the killing process (with a time out at beginning) in background before executing `a|b`, e.g. `(sleep 20; while pgrep myProcA; do sleep 1; done; pkill myProcB ) & `

Comment: this probably should be a feature of `fzf` as it can react at the time of EOF on read of `stdin`; other methods would be way more complicated